# libpam-shield config allow certain IP addresses

Tags: debian, pam

`libpam-shield`'s config file `/etc/security/shield.conf` has a line that says `allow HOSTNAME`. The `man` pages for `shield.conf(8)` says that `HOSTNAME` can be name, or IP address or network/mask or network in CIDR. In order to test this, I added  `allow 192.168.52.3`. In the `shield.conf` file, `max_conns` is `3`. On the third failed attempt from `192.168.52.3`, that machine is blocked, while earlier lines in the log seem to suggest that `libpam-shield` has understood that this IP is to be white-listed.

```
May 20 22:48:38 access1 PAM-shield[2322]: logging debug info
May 20 22:48:38 access1 PAM-shield[2322]: allowing from localhost
May 20 22:48:38 access1 PAM-shield[2322]: allowing from 127.0.0.1/255.0.0.0
May 20 22:48:38 access1 PAM-shield[2322]: allowing from 192.168.52.3/255.255.255.255
May 20 22:48:38 access1 PAM-shield[2322]: done reading config file, 0 errors
May 20 22:48:38 access1 PAM-shield[2322]: user <redacted>
May 20 22:48:38 access1 PAM-shield[2322]: remotehost 192.168.52.3
May 20 22:48:38 access1 PAM-shield[2322]: missing DNS entry for 192.168.52.3 (allowed)
May 20 22:48:38 access1 PAM-shield[2322]: remoteip 192.168.52.3
May 20 22:48:38 access1 PAM-shield[2322]: 3 times from 192.168.52.3
May 20 22:48:38 access1 PAM-shield[2322]: running command 'add 192.168.52.3'
May 20 22:48:38 access1 shield-trigger[2325]: blocking 192.168.52.3
```

I am using `libpam-shield` (0.9.6-1.2+b1) from Debian stretch (stable), installed using `apt install`.

Added: How do I tell `libpam-shield` to `allow` a specific IP address (or a range of them), even if there are multiple failed authentication attempts from it/them?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Added the question.